# Python_Problem_with_socket_programming

Tags: sockets, connection-refused

Well, it seems that I have a small problem with a simple socket programming example.

The goal is to use the vidstream in the raspberrypi 4- OS raspbian 10 (I have managed to install vidstream properly - if you want help with that, please feel free to ask) in order to send video and audio streaming.
I use the following code via PyCharm (Python 3.7).

```py
from vidstream import StreamingServer
import socket

#host = socket.gethostbyname("raspberrypi")
#print(host)

server = StreamingServer('127.0.0.1',5000)

from vidstream import CameraClient
from vidstream import VideoClient
from vidstream import ScreenShareClient

client1 = CameraClient('127.0.0.1',5000)

client1.start_stream()
```

And I get as a return the following error

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:

Traceback (most recent call last):


  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner

    self.run()

  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run

    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

  File "/home/pi/PycharmProjects/pythonProject5/venv/lib/python3.7/site-
packages/vidstream/streaming.py", line 269, in __client_streaming

    self.__client_socket.connect((self.__host, self.__port))

ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I would like to mention that:
I have checked the localhost (127.0.0.1) and port 5000 (also I have tried other ports such as 8888 and 9999). Moreover, I know that by default the Raspbian 10 does not uses an active firewall.

I use the same device, as server and client.

In order to avoid my router's firewall I have tested the code in 2 modes :  1. With the router’s firewall shut down 2. With the wifi of raspberry shut down, and the problem remains.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere that you are starting your server. Add `server.start_server()` after `server = StreamingServer('127.0.0.1',5000)`. You will then call `server.stop_server()` once you are doing using the server.

Comment: Oops !!! you are right """""my silly mistake!!!!!""""" sometimes we forgot the obvious. I am really sorry for the inconvenience. Really, thanks purple.